# MIN function in ORACLE and SQL Server working differently

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sorting

I am trying to convert the Oracle script to SQL Server script. But it seems my `MIN()` function is not working as expected as it is being executed in Oracle.

For **SQL Server** :

```
SELECT MIN(v)  
FROM (VALUES ('20013E17587A1_2'), ('20013E17587_2')) AS value(v);

Result: 20013E17587_2
```

However,

For **ORACLE :**

```
SELECT MIN(t.value)  
  FROM tab t;

Result: 20013E17587A1_2
```

I am getting this as a result. Can somebody explain why is this difference and what can be done to have same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different sort rules. You're asking the database whether it considers `_` to come before or after `A`. By default, Oracle uses a binary sort (and the code point 65 belonging to `A` is less than code point 95 belonging to `_`) while SQL Server uses the default collation of the database, which will be a linguistic ordering where `_` is considered to precede any letter. If you want SQL Server to exhibit identical behavior, use something like

```
SELECT MIN(v COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2) 
FROM (VALUES ('20013E17587A1_2'), ('20013E17587_2')) AS value(v);
```

Actual correct placement of the `COLLATE` depends on your "real" query, which I presume this isn't -- you may want to change the collation of the column itself in the `CREATE TABLE`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Because Oracle looks for the **ASCII** value for each character during the comparison of each respective character ordered within the string while performing alphanumeric sorting. This is called **binary sort** *which's default for Oracle DB*.

`ASCII('A')` equals **65**, and `ASCII('_')` equals **95**. If the string was `20013E17587.2` instead of `20013E17587_2`, then you'd get `20013E17587.2` as result, since `ASCII('.')` equals **46** which is less than **65**.

Comment: The actual sorting used by Oracle largely depends on the *collation* setting, which can be specified on many levels (database, table, column, statement). Though in this particular case, it makes no difference, since the strings are all ASCII.

Comment: @Barbaros.. In your answer's second sentence you mentioned ASCII('A')=65 and later you mentioned ASCII('A') is 46 which is less than 65. Is it 65 lesser than 95 or Am I understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: thank you @SathiyaKumar , I just meant `ASCII('.')` but I realise that misprinted.

Comment: Thank you @BarbarosÖzhan.. By the way it is good answer :)